# Бот вк Long Poll падает с ошибкой internal server error

Tags: java, вконтакте, бот

Бот вк Long Poll падает с ошибкой internal server error через несколько часов работы, но max_msg_id передается.

```java
    public message.entity.Message getInput() {
        if(!queue.isEmpty())
            return handle();
        else
        {
            getUpdates();
            return null;
        }
    }
    void getUpdates()
    {
        MessagesGetLongPollHistoryQuery eventsQuery = vk.messages().getLongPollHistory(actor).ts(ts);

        if (maxMsgId > 0) {
            eventsQuery.maxMsgId(maxMsgId);
        }

        List<Message> messages;
        try {
            messages = eventsQuery.execute().getMessages().getItems();
            for(Message m: messages)
            {
                queue.offer(m);
            }
        } catch (ApiException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (ClientException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (!messages.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                try {
                    ts = vk.messages().getLongPollServer(actor).execute().getTs();
                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (ClientException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }
    message.entity.Message handle()
    {
        Message m = queue.remove();

        if ( !m.isOut()) {
            int messageId = m.getId();
            if (messageId > maxMsgId){
                maxMsgId = messageId;
            }
            message.entity.Message simpleMessage = new SimpleMessage(m.getText() , m.getPeerId() + "");
            return simpleMessage;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы стабильно получаете ошибку `internal server error` на каком-то запросе то надо посмотреть с какими параметрами вы его вызываете, скорей всего передаете что-то совсем неправильное.

Если `internal server error` появляется иногда, то это "нормально", ошибка может возникать когда сервера перегружены, в этом случае можно повторить тот-же запрос через секунду.